# autoplay video not playing on iOS (Safari) in production

Tags: html, ios, reactjs, iphone, safari

i want to add a loop video on my react-app.
I did it like this

```
 <video
   ref={videoRef}
   playsInline
   autoPlay
   muted
   loop>
  <source src={Video} type='video/mp4' />
</video>
```

it's working fine on Chrome/Firefox on mobile and on desktop.
But it's **not** playing on **iPhone** (Safari).
It is playing **locally** but when i **deploy** it. it's not playing :(

Comment: i also tried this - https://medium.com/@BoltAssaults/autoplay-muted-html5-video-safari-ios-10-in-react-673ae50ba1f5
still not working

Comment: Can you provide minimal reproducible on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-video-player-r3vmy)?

Comment: can you add browsers used and version

Comment: @oldmayn i made a page for you , mind if you test it using a video from youtube

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-ganguly-tfbg2?file=/src/App.js) and [deployed](https://otaviodeaguiar.github.io/csb-tfbg2/) but was unable to reproduce your issue on iOS 15.2 (iPhone 12), it autoplays and loops as expected. Could please add more details?

Comment: Thanks for the sandbox, i encountered a problem with iOS loading videos that are locally saved. So i ended up loading the videos online from a cloud and everything is working fine since.

Comment: I'm trying your sandbox on Safari 15.6.1 and I get a play button in the middle...

Comment: Version 15.6 (17613.3.9.1.5) and play button in the middle

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar kind of requirement with my previous project, the following code is working fine, from this we will have a **muted** video running **in loop** with **autoplay**.

```html
 <video width="300px" height="500px" autoplay="autoplay" muted loop>
       <source src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/27606753/144578902-9b14dc56-9056-4650-942f-4d25f0ecbcc1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
 </video>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is so because, according to the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/delivering_video_content_for_safari#3030251), a video only plays automatically if:

- it contains the `playsinline` attribute, and
- it has no audio track present OR it contains the `muted` attribute.

So I'd suggest you include the `playsinline` attribute. Learn more on inline playback [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/delivering_video_content_for_safari#3030250).

Comment: i tried it already like i mentioned at the top